# JVM Internals - Why does the same piece of code runs in different timings?

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to understand the JVM options and came across the option `CompileThreshold`. I am running the below program:

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main (String [] args) {    
        for (int repeat = 0; repeat < 200; ++ repeat) {    
            long start = System.nanoTime();    
            sum (100);    
            long end = System.nanoTime();    
            long diff = end - start;    
            System.out.println (repeat + ": " + diff);    
        }    
    }    `

    public static int sum (int n) {
        if (n <= 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return n + sum (n - 1);
    }
}
```

I get the below output:

```
0: 8555
1: 6416
2: 6416
3: 5988
4: 6416
5: 8555
6: 5989
7: 6416
8: 6416
9: 5988
10: 5561
11: 5988
12: 5988
13: 5988
14: 5988
15: 5988
16: 5988
17: 5988
18: 5988
19: 6416
20: 5988
21: 5988
22: 5988
23: 5988
24: 5560
25: 6416
26: 5988
27: 5561
28: 5560
29: 5989
30: 5989
31: 5988
32: 21814
33: 6416
34: 6843
35: 6416
36: 6844
37: 6416
38: 6416
39: 6844
40: 6416
41: 6415
42: 6416
43: 5988
44: 6416
45: 6844
46: 6416
47: 6416
48: 6416
49: 6416
50: 6416
51: 6416
52: 5988
53: 6416
54: 6844
55: 6843
56: 6416
57: 6844
58: 6416
59: 6416
60: 6415
61: 6416
62: 6416
63: 6416
64: 5988
65: 5988
66: 6416
67: 6416
68: 6844
69: 6416
70: 6416
71: 6416
72: 6416
73: 6416
74: 6415
75: 6416
76: 6416
77: 6416
78: 6416
79: 6415
80: 6844
81: 5988
82: 6415
83: 6416
84: 6416
85: 6416
86: 6416
87: 6416
88: 7272
89: 6416
90: 6416
91: 6844
92: 6844
93: 6415
94: 6416
95: 6415
96: 6415
97: 6416
98: 6416
99: 25236
100: 6416
101: 6416
102: 6843
103: 6416
104: 5988
105: 6416
106: 6415
107: 6416
108: 6416
109: 6416
110: 6416
111: 6416
112: 6416
113: 6844
114: 6416
115: 6416
116: 6416
117: 5988
118: 6416
119: 6416
120: 6416
121: 6415
122: 6416
123: 6415
124: 6416
125: 6416
126: 6416
127: 6416
128: 5988
129: 5988
130: 6416
131: 6416
132: 5988
133: 5988
134: 6416
135: 6416
136: 5989
137: 6416
138: 6416
139: 5988
140: 5988
141: 6416
142: 5560
143: 5988
144: 6416
145: 6843
146: 6415
147: 6416
148: 6843
149: 11549
150: 6416
151: 6844
152: 6416
153: 6415
154: 6416
155: 5988
156: 5988
157: 6416
158: 6416
159: 6416
160: 6416
161: 6415
162: 6416
163: 6416
164: 6416
165: 6416
166: 5988
167: 5988
168: 5988
169: 6416
170: 6416
171: 6416
172: 5988
173: 5988
174: 6844
175: 5988
176: 6416
177: 6416
178: 6844
179: 6416
180: 6415
181: 6416
182: 5988
183: 5989
184: 6416
185: 6416
186: 6416
187: 6416
188: 5989
189: 5560
190: 5988
191: 6416
192: 6415
193: 6416
194: 18820
195: 1711
196: 1284
197: 2139
198: 1711
199: 1711
```

If you observe, there are spikes in the times at 32, 99, 149, 194.

After 194, the time taken to run is comparitively less. Please explain this behaviour. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The initial spike is the JIT kicking in to decide to compile the code, the rest of them are GC runs.

Comment: How does CompileThreshold play a role in this ? Could you please explain?

Comment: This doesn't explain the 3x speed increase after 194

Comment: One more question? Before JIT kicks in, does interpretation does the work?

Answer (score 1):

Most likly HotSpot in JVM re-JITs method after that many calls causing speedup after 194 run:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppHotspot.fm.html

> B.5.3 CompileThreshold
>
> Default Value: 1500
>
> Example Usage: java -XX:CompileThreshold=1000000
>
> The current implementation of HotSpot usually waits for a method to be executed a certain number of times before it is compiled. Not compiling every method helps startup time and reduces RAM footprint. This option allows you to control that threshold. By increasing the number, you can trade slight reductions in RAM footprint in exchange for a longer period of time before your program reaches peak performance.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this question is incomplete unless you mention the activity of the other processes running in the background/foreground i.e. without understanding the overall system load, it's kind of difficult to *predict* the reason for those timings. When running such benchmarks, make sure you capture/monitor the entire system load or at least make sure *no* background activities are running i.e. virus scans etc. Plus you are missing out other might-be-vital information like the JVM version, the platform and the number of cores.

Would it be possible to confirm the same and re-post your results?

Comment: I am running a standalone program. The jvm version is 1.6.0